# How to prove a finite field is not ordered?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, ordered-fields

I have a set S={0,1}, and the addition and multiplication rules are 
\begin{array}{c|cc}
+&0&1\\ \hline
0&0&1\\
1&1&0
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|cc}
*&0&1\\ \hline
0&0&0\\
1&0&1
\end{array}

It is sure that it is a field. How can I prove this field can be ordered or not?

Comment: There are only two possible orderings.  Try them.

Comment: Well,  there's only one field of 2 elements....but here you can use brute force.    If there is an order,  it is either 0<1 or 1<0.   Check your properties that an order must have to see if either of those work

Comment: $\underbrace{1+1+1+\dots+1}_n>0$ for any $n$ in an ordered field. Then…

Comment: @egreg Umm,  no,  1+1=0,  which is not >0 :)

Comment: @Alan, its a proof by contradiction. Suppose the field can be ordered then $1+1>0$. But as you point out $1+1=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Answered already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/650875/11619), but somehow I'm not sure closing as a duplicate is appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

An ordered field $F$ must have characteristic $0$, because
$$
\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_n > 0
$$
for all $n>0$. A finite field can't have characteristic $0$.

Comment: is it common that in an ordered field that a>0 and b>0 then a+b>0?

Comment: @user2841003 That's part of the definition.

Comment: so how about I define that 1<0 or 0<1? In both cases I add 1 to both side and get a contradicting result to the assumption.

Comment: @user2841003 Either $1>0$ or $1<0$; but in the second case $-1>0$, so $(-1)(-1)>0$: a contradiction. So $1>0$.

Answer (score 1):

If it is ordered, that means there is a nonempty subset $P$ such that
(1) for each $x$ exactly one of $x \in P, x=0, -x\in P$
(2) If $x,y \in P$ then each of $x+y,x*y$ is in $P$.
There are not many choices for $P$ here. $P$ cannot have $0$ in it, otherwise (1) above is false. And $P$ is nonempty. So far the only possible $P$ is $P=\{1\}.$
But this $P$ does not satisfy (2) since $1 \in P$ but $1 + 1=0$ is not in $P.$
[Thanks to @egreg for noticing my previous $1*1=0$ version wasn't right.]

*Added:* An easier way to see it can't be ordered: Assume that $a<b$ is incompatible with $b<a$, and that one can always add the same thing to both sides of an inequality. Then since $1 \neq 0$ we have either $0<1$ or else $1<0$ (but not both). However adding $1$ to each side of either of these gives the other, i.e. a contradiction.

Comment: It should be $1+1=0$ at the end.

Comment: @egreg That's right, will fix.